# Python: Merging multiple dictionaries in a list with an update of values

Tags: python, dictionary

Here is my list of dictionaries:

```
dict_list=[{'red':3, 'orange':4}, {'blue':1, 'red':2},
   {'brown':4, 'orange':7}, {'blue':4, 'pink':10}]
```

Here's my `desired outcome`

```
[{'red':5, 'orange':11, 'blue':5, 'brown':4, 'pink':10}]
```

I have tried using sum but got an error message, update doesn't seem suitable here.

```
 update_dict={}
 for x in dict_list:
     for a in x.items():
         update_dict+= x[a]
```

Any suggestions? thanks.

Comment: Please post your code. Thanks!

Comment: You're trying to sum `int` and `str`, which will error out. Ensure that your dict is properly formatted.

Comment: Are you really sure you want the numbers to be in strings and numbers as in your `desired outcome`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`defaultdict` is your friend.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(int)

for subdict in dict_list:
    for k,v in subdict.items():
        d[k] += int(v)
```

Python 3 syntax.  The `int(v)` is necessary because you have mixed string and int values in your dictionaries.

To get to your desired output:

```
d
Out[16]: defaultdict(<class 'int'>, {'orange': 11, 'blue': 5, 'pink': 10, 'red': 5, 'brown': 4})

[dict(d)]
Out[17]: [{'blue': 5, 'brown': 4, 'orange': 11, 'pink': 10, 'red': 5}]
```

Comment: @roippi I wrote this code some time back. But carefully look at his expected output.

Comment: @thefourtheye I assume the mixed ints and strings are a mistake, as for example '3' + 2 = '5' for `red`.  If he *really* wants a list with a single dictionary in it, well, ok.

Comment: Hi @roippi, thanks for the solution. Perhaps you might want to update your answer to make it a dictionary list.

Answer (score 0):

Let's simplify this a bit by converting your `dict_list` into a list of tuples. `itertools.chain` is good at this sort of thing.

```
from itertools import chain

dict_list=[{'red':'3', 'orange':4}, {'blue':'1', 'red':2},
  {'brown':'4', 'orange':7}, {'blue':'4', 'pink':10}]

def dict_sum_maintain_types(dl):
  pairs = list(chain.from_iterable(i.items() for i in dl))

  # Initialize the result dict. 
  result = dict.fromkeys(chain(*dl), 0)

  # Sum the values as integers.
  for k, v in pairs:
    result[k] += int(v)

  # Use the type of the original values as a function to cast the new values
  # back to their original type.
  return [dict((k, type(dict(pairs)[k])(v)) for k, v in result.items())] 

>>> dict_sum_maintain_types(dict_list)
[{'orange': 11, 'blue': '5', 'pink': 10, 'red': 5, 'brown': '4'}]
```